# add TouchListener to Drawable

Tags: android, drawing

I want to make a Drawable touchable for a component I am creating, does anyone know how to do that?

```
final Drawable selected = backgroundSelected;

selected.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 90);
selected.draw(canvas);
canvas.save();
```

Comment: You cannot do this directly. You need a View to capture touch events.

Comment: Oke, so how can I do this indirectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using an onTouch event, and then checking the coordinates of the touch against the coordinates of the Drawable.